# In Bootstrap inline-form after form-group must be a new line/whitespace?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote the html part as below:

`<div class="row"><form action="/Admin/ClientText" class="form-inline" method="post"> <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="Query_Category1">Category1</label><input class="form-control" id="category1" name="Query.Category1" placeholder="Category1" type="text" value="" /></div><div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only" for="Query_Category2">Category2</label><input class="form-control" id="Query_Category2" name="Query.Category2" type="text" value="" /></div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button></form></div>`

As you see there is nothing between the closing part of  and the next
.

The markup with newlines/whitespaces is:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgeza/TRDSV/

in first case there is no space between input boxes, the secod case is correct.
Why is new line is important? Any workaorund?

Comment: this is not a boostrap thing its an html thing `this  this` vs `this this` is going to display differently because of white space if its `inline`

Comment: Strange I haven't noticed that. I make html code more then 15 years:)

Comment: here is the in detail http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/